# 'wish" vs "expect" and "to" vs "for"

Tags: prepositions, verbs

> I hope you know that I expect the same things to you, too.

I'm not sure if *expect* is the most appropriate verb to use but express it more what I want to say. Also, I have a doubt about *to you* or *for you* in the sentence above.

Comment: I guess it is nicer to show the effort you already made, such as 
[the definition/explanation and examples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/) or
[grammar rules and examples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/) 
in a dictionary or other trusted reference.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! @Marcela, could you phrase this as a single question with conext, like, "Is 'expect' the right verb here in the context where...."?  Also, if you have two questions, then you can ask two separate questions to make it simpler to answer.

Comment: This question needs more focus, you should only ask one question in a post.

Answer (score 0):

Some more context would help.
 Usually, it's "expect .... from" or "expect of" if you mean something the other person should do or provide.
 If you mean that you expect the same thing to happen to someone else, it could be "expect for".
   Example sentences:
 "I expect more context information from you."
 "I expect good answers for you with more context."